# Show that invertible matrices with an additional condition are diagonalizable.

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices such that $AB = -BA$ over the complex numbers. Show that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable.

Comment: The title of this question is highly misleading. Perhaps adding "with an additional condition" after "matrices" would be more accurate.

Answer (score 9):

Fill in details:

Let $\;\lambda\;$ be an eigenvalue of $\;A\;$ with corresponding eigenvector $\;v\;$ :

$$ABv=A(Bv)=-BAv=-B(\lambda v)=-\lambda Bv$$

and thus **also** $\;-\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;A\;$ with corr. eigenvector $\;Bv\;$ .

Since $\;\lambda\neq0\;$ we get $\;A\;$ is diagonalizable, and by symmetry also $\;B\;$ is.

Answer (score 6):

We have $B=A^{-1}(-B)A$, hence $B$ and $-B$ are similar. Since $B$ is invertible , $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$.

Now, if $\lambda_0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, then $-\lambda_0$ is an eigenvalue of $-B$. By similarity:  $-\lambda_0$  is an eigenvalue of $B$.

The $2 \times 2$ - matrix $B$ has therefore the two distinct eigenvalues  $\lambda_0$ and  $-\lambda_0$

Comment: Maybe a bit pedantic but I would mention that $B$ definitely has an eigenvalue to begin with since we are over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Sebastian: Du hast vollkommen recht, auch wenns pedantisch ist. It is pedantic, but you are right.